# C array alignment check at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

I am trying to check an array alignment of 8 at compile time. This is the code:

```
// File scope
uint32_t pool[1024];
bool aligned = (((uintptr_t) pool) % 8) == 0;
```

I get this error: initializer element is not computable at load time. However, when I check the array alignment of 4, I don't get the error. The code below:

```
// File scope
uint32_t pool[1024];
bool aligned = (((uintptr_t) pool) % 4) == 0;
```

Language: C

Toolchain: arm-none-eabi-gcc

Compiler options: -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb

Why is this happening?

Comment: why do you think it is done at the compile time? The expression you wrote is a runtime expression... what do I miss?

Comment: The compiler is probably requiring 4-byte alignment for `pool`, and is smart enough to realize that the address mod 4 will be 0 no matter what aligned address is used.  The same cannot be said for the address mod 8, which will presumably be either 0 or 4.

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you, your comment is what I was looking for.

Comment: Compiler options of what compiler? Please add a tag for the compiler used. Also, it isn't obvious if `aligned` is declared at local scope or file scope, which matters a lot.

Comment: There could be some issue in casting, confirm it please. Moreover do you get both 0 and 1 in aligned variable on different runs?

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to enforce 8-byte alignment for the pool, then you wouldn't need to check

Comment: @Lundin Please read the question. The compiler toolchain is given since the very first version of the question.

Comment: @harper That's not the point. If you don't tag the question gcc, then you might block all gcc experts from finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of a static variable isn't known at *compile* time, it's only decided later by the linker. There is no suitable relocation for "address of a symbol modulo some arbitrary number" that the compiler can emit as the initialisation value for the linker to fix up, so it gives up. As Tom says in the comments, it *can* at least assume that the linker isn't going to violate the minimum required alignment for the type, so is able to optimise the expression away in that case.

The only way I think you could achieve this as-is would be to just declare it as `extern bool aligned`, then use some linker script black magic to define it with the appropriate value at link time.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to enforce a particular alignment, this is reported to work for the "arm-none-eabi-gcc" toolchain:

`uint32_t pool[1024] __attribute__((aligned(8)));`

Comment: This is getting at the answer to the question it seems OP didn't know to ask.